# How solve this answer [AsyncFunction: response]?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I execute this function for a test in nodejs

```
const response = async () => {return await MyService.Adding({name})}
console.log(response)
```

but i get this: [AsyncFunction: response]

i want to use:

```
const res = await (async () => {
            const response = await MyService.Adding({name})
            return response
       })()
       
        console.log('RESPONDE ', res, expected)
```

Comment: can you try `response.then(console.log).catch(console.error)` ? I know it should directly give you the answer but just try it out maybe it's getting error?

Comment: @HalilÇakar can you answer me please

Comment: It seems like you have to understand how the Async function works in JavaScript. I found a good article about the Async function: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: @LaodeMuhammadAlFatih i am trying but dont worked for me, answer me please

Comment: ALL async functions return a promise.  So, when you call an async function, the caller will have to use `.then()` or `await` to get the value from it.  There is no way around that at all.  Also, there is no point in `return await fn()`.  It does exactly the same thing as `return fn()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in the `async` function, just use `await` to run the other `async` functions.

**Example**

```js
const res = await MyService.Adding({
  name
})
```

**Try:**

```js
// Just for example
const MyService = {
  Adding: async (params) => params
}

async function main() {
  const res = await MyService.Adding({
    name: 'Your Name'
  })

  console.log(res)
}

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a function to response
You want to eval the function in order to get the expected response.
Something like this:

```
let response2 = (async () => {return await MyService.Adding({name})})()
```

But if you are writing a small script, and you want to use await, you can't do it without an async function. So your script should be refactor to something like this:

```
(async () => {
     const response = await MyService.Adding({name})
     console.log(response);
})()
```

Your whole script can be written in the implicit evaluation of an async function and await will work.
It is not very preatty, but is better that managing callbacks